# What is Neo being bathed in when he wakes up and is being flushed down after taking the pill?

Tags: the-matrix

What is Neo being bathed in when he wakes up and is being flushed down after taking the pill in the Matrix? Is it amniotic fluid?

Comment: Actually, it's the pink slime from Ghostbusters 2. Being immersed in positively-charged slime keeps the coppertops happy & oblivious.

Answer (score 10):

#### While it is likely not specifically [amniotic fluid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amniotic_fluid), it serves to perform many of the same functions include waste management, cellular replacement and physical development The fluid is certainly sterile and filled with a variety of nutritional capacities.

- The fluid maintains a temperature-controlled environment protecting the human body from extremes of heat or cold. It regulates the body temperature of the human inside as well especially during potential imbalances in the body's health status.
- The fluid certainly aids in the physical development of the body internally and externally providing the capacity for cellular development, waste management, and stem cell application, in the same manner as amniotic fluid. This fluid is
- It also allowed an environment for the human body to float in, preventing the formation of [pressure ulcers or bedsores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedsores) which can be dangerous to a Human in an immobile state.

The machine society had to have an extremely developed technology to be able to replicate both in terms of volume and capacity the amount of fluid needed to keep millions of humans alive and functioning.

[image]

Comment: "While it is likely not specifically amniotic fluid, it serves to perform many of the same functions include waste management, cellular replacement and physical development" How do you conclude then that it's likely not af?

Comment: Do you know anywhere to make tens of billions of gallons of amniotic fluid without women to do so? Last time I checked high quality artificial amniotic fluid does not yet exist... And given the technology required to create such fluid tailored to each individual to ensure proper development, is something HUMANITY will be quite some time in doing, IF EVER. [Artificial Amniotic Fluid](http://news.ufl.edu/2002/11/12/amnioticfluid/)

Comment: The pools don't look like they were created by humans in their end form(sure they are but I am talking movie logic here). If a human gives a computer a starting point and creates an ai, the computer can optimize. And the same applies to the fluid. The fluid is just chemistry, if a biological machine, a human, can create it, a computer can aswell. If you can create it once, you can recreate. Maybe the machines are able to create every element they want. Then they take the most frequent material and change it to what they need. There you have the huge amount of whatever you want.

Comment: BTW: If you want to prove a point in the matrix realm, you must use movie logic.

Comment: @Zurechtweiser you appear to be arguing just for the sake of arguing. You asked if it's amniotic fluid but when someone says probably not you're calling them on it. There's no evidence of nanotechnology in The Matrix which is one of the other possible solutions. If this is a genuine question then at least have the decency to consider the answer

Comment: Are there sources for this claims about what this fluid is, other than just a buoyant liquid or maybe even a way to extract the electrical energy of people?

Comment: Is this answer sourced anywhere? It feels like pure speculation.

Answer (score 3):

According to Sati, the fluid is oxygenated '*bio-gel*'. Unsurprisingly, it has some of the same properties as amniotic fluid.

> Fifty meters below the Anomaleum is a stratum of amniotic filters. Hidden along this edge is a small hexagonal vent. **This vent feeds the air intake into the corpuscular modifier, which oxygenates the bio-gel used in Neo’s pod.**
>
> <sub><sup>The Matrix Resurrections</sup></sub>